# Why I cannot refresh contents of ListWindow

Tags: java, timer, jframe, invalidation, pack

So this is my situation:
I have a timer and it updates values in the background until a value has reached a certain point.

But in order for me to see each update of value I currently have to add in a 
"new ListWindow();" statement in my for loop.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class Timing here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Timing
{

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Timing
 */
public static void Timer()
  {
    Timer timer = new Timer(250, new TimerListener());
    timer.start();
  }

private static class TimerListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        while(valX != 100)
        {
            Timer();
            MainProg.valX += 5;   
            // new ListWindow(); //statement goes here. it creates a new window
                                 //each time it updates the value.
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is: I do not want a new window. I want the list that the value comes from (see below) to update its value and refresh the list in the current window. perhaps on a button click.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Component.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class ListWindow here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class ListWindow extends JFrame
{
    private    JPanel StatsPanel; //holds stats
    private    JPanel ButtonPanel; //holds stats
    private    JList StatList; //inventory

    private    JButton RefreshButton; // a button

    private    String[] Stats = 
               {"Stuff " + Stuff, "Value " + valX, "Test " + per};

/**
 * Constructor 
 */
public ListWindow()
{
    setTitle("STATS");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    buildStatsPanel();
    buildButtonPanel();
    RefreshButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    add(StatsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(ButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public    void buildStatsPanel()
{
    StatsPanel = new JPanel();

    StatList = new JList(Stats);

    StatList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);



    StatsPanel.add(StatList);
}

public    void buildButtonPanel()
{
    ButtonPanel = new JPanel();

    RefreshButton = new JButton("Refresh");

    ButtonPanel.add(RefreshButton);

}
private    class ButtonListener
implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        if(actionCommand.equals("Refresh"))
        {
            pack();
            invalidate();
            validate();
        }
    }
}

public    void RunMain(String[] args)
{
    new ListWindow();
}

}
```

Also: this is my main method where I run things from. You should also notice that I have main methods in my other two snippets I pasted here. I did this so I could run things individually for quick debugging and future use.

```
/**
 * Write a description of class MainProg here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class MainProg
{
public static int stuff = 100;
public static int valX = 0;
public static int per = 100;    
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Game
 */
public static void main()
{
  new MoveWindow();
  new ListWindow();
  while (valX != 100)
  {
      Timing.Timer();
    }
}
}
```

I am very new to java, i have looked for other solutions and was unable to find what I think i need. Perhaps I did find it, and did not recognize it as a solution.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Call a function that updates the list (the default JList is rather inflexible and you may need to use a different ListModel rather than the default) with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Call a function that updates the list (the default `JList` `ListModel` used when supplying a Object array is rather inflexible and you may need to use a different `ListModel` rather than the default) with the new value.

Comment: I assume that the effect of what you are suggesting would look similar to this?
[link] (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleofJListwithaDefaultListModel.htm)

What i am after has a similar effect.
I would like the timer in my code to update the value valX, and update it in the panel as well. From what i can see though, the code in this link removes items entirely and adds new items instead of changing them.

Comment: Unless you change the ListModel, you can't change individual elements.  See the sample code at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html
"a read-only view of the data"

Comment: Thanks! Ill try some stuff and see what i can do.